# Parse a section of the JSON data to the Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am very new to backbone and I'm trying to integrate backbone in my project. I have a large `JSON` file that's been used in the project. My `views` will be mainly driven by the data from the `JSON` file.

The sample JSON looks like this.

```
{
    "Cases": [
        {
            "x": "Cat",
            "y": 12, 
        }
    ],
    "Summary": [
        {
            "date" : "18/06/2014",
            "data" :{
                "ALL" : [
                    "Items" : 0
                ],
                "Cat" : [
                    "Items" : 10
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My collection looks like this, and all I want to use from the `JSON`is the **`Summary`**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : DataModel,
        url : 'path/to/my/data.json',
        parse : function(response, xhr) {
            // I only want the Summary returned
            console.log(response.Summary); // Prints exactly what I need
            return response.Summary;
        }
    });

    return DataCollection;
});
```

My view looks like this

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', '../../collections/DataCollection'], function($, _, Backbone, DataCollection) {

    var AppVIew = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function() {
            var myData = new DataCollection();
            console.log(myData.fetch({}) );
        }
    });

    return AppVIew;
});
```

When I try printing what's been fetched I get the following and the response from server, and under "responseText" key the entire JSON not what `response.Summary`

```
Object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
```

Can some one help on how do to solve this problem of mine. Came across a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062605/how-to-handle-custom-response-in-backbone-model) but didn't help.

Any help/advice will be appreciated, to go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` returns a XHR object. You should check the collection's data, not the returned value of the `fetch` call.

```
myData.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response, options) {
      console.log(collection.models);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.
When backbone calls Fetch function, it uses Jquery(ajax) from behind and it means that fetch is Async. To receive the result of the Fetch requisition you can have something like this.

coffeescript code.
    //Inside your model 
    result = @fetch()

Fetch returns the jqXHR(good to know about your request), here you can find some informations like status code of request, etc..

But if you want to know the attributes of your model/collection after a request, you need to listen for an event that will be triggered after backbone finish the fetch request.

```
//Inside your model
getResult:-> 
  @fetch(
     success:=>
        @trigger "success"
     error:=>
        @trigger "error"
```

)

```
//Inside your view
@model = new Model()
@model.getResult()
@model.on "succees", @doSomethingForSuccess, @
@model.on "error", @doSomethingForError, @


doSomethingForSuccess:->
 //implementation

doSomethingForError:->
 // implementation
```

Now you have the Model populate with the server content. If you try to console.log inside "doSomethingForSuccess" function, you will see the content information.

Backbone have some defaults trigger events when communicate with server.
take a look at the oficial documentation.
http://backbonejs.org/#Events