# Accessing Backbone collection properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was going through a stack overflow question on [handling collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062605/how-to-handle-custom-response-in-backbone-model). The answer given by [Brian Genisio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36687/brian-genisio) was pretty convincing. I have tried his approach as follows:

**Collection definition**

```
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : Person,
  url: '/people',
  parse: function(resp, xhr) {
    this.header = resp.header;
    this.stats = resp.stats;
    return resp.people;
  }
});
```

**Collection usage**

```
var personCollection = new PersonCollection();
personCollection.fetch();
console.log(personCollection.header);  //undefined
console.log(personCollection.status);  //undefined
```

The collection is fetching models perfectly but I am getting other assigned properties  as undefined. Please suggest me a solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the fetch is done.

```
personCollection.fetch().done(() => {
  console.log(personCollection.header);
  console.log(personCollection.status);
});
```